# How to get fastapi type conversion str->bool?

Tags: python, fastapi, python-typing, pydantic

I have external service. It call my api with get parameters

```
class Misc(BaseModel):
    # - whether to pop-up checkbox ("true" or "false")
    popup: Optional[str] = None
    # - whether an advertisement is pending to be displayed ("yes" or "no")
    advertPending: Optional[str] = None
```

I want to convert `"true"` or `"false"`, `"yes"` or `"no"`, `"on"` or `"off"`, `"1"` or `"0"`, `"y"` or `"n"` to bool. How to do that?

```
class Misc(BaseModel):
    # - whether to pop-up checkbox ("true" or "false")
    popup: bool = False
    # - whether an advertisement is pending to be displayed ("yes" or "no")
    advertPending: bool = False
```

Comment: There is no need to do anything at all; [Pydantic already handles this for you if you've defined the field as boolean](https://docs.pydantic.dev/2.0/usage/types/booleans/): `a str which when converted to lower case is one of '0', 'off', 'f', 'false', 'n', 'no', '1', 'on', 't', 'true', 'y', 'yes'`. So this should work with your example without changing anything or writing any code.

Answer (score 1):

```
from pydantic.functional_validators import PlainValidator

def strToBool(v:str)->bool:
    v = v.strip().lower()
    if v in ["y","yes","on","1","enabled","true"]:
        return True
    if v in ["n","no","off","0","disabled","false"]
        return False
    

extendedBool = Annotated[bool, PlainValidator(strToBool)]
```

Comment: This is already built-in to Pydantic for the bool type. No need for a custom type or custom validator (you've introduced `enabled` and `disabled` here which aren't in your quesiton, but generally Pydantic by itself already supports what you asked for.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about fastapi, but it is possible with python :\

```
positive_list = ['true', 'yes', 'on', '1', 'y']
x = 'true'
popup = False

for y in positive_list:
    if x == y:
        popup = True
```

Comment: I want to fastapi do this and return clean model to request